# How do I send one of the "new" messageboxes?

Tags: c#, windows-8

How do I send this:

[image]

I remember that in desktop C# it was MessageBox.Show(All those arguments);

I don't know how to google a question like this because I know nothing about them.. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a `MessageBox`, it's a "toast". Here's the basics - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-notifications-sample-52eeba29

Comment: Because it "pops up", like toast.

Comment: Android also has Toast class.